# InfoPath 2007 Files upload features

Tags: 2007, infopath, library, pdf, jpg

I have an InfoPath 2007 form that allows people to upload two type of files - PDF and JPG.

When the user submits the form, it will store into the SharePoint as an entry in a Library.

Is it possible that when I open the entry from the Library inside the SharePoint, it will display the PDF and JPG on the form itself?

Currently, it only displays the file name only. What I wish to do is that it display the JPG image onto the form and the PDF content onto the form but would that be possible?

If is impossible, are there are an alternative method such that when opening the form, the content in both PDF and JPG are also displayed?